# Multiple fixed price abilities on armor

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, armor, pricing

How does one price the creation of magical armor with more than one ability with a fixed GP price?
The table in "Creating Magical Items" points you to [Table 7-5](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicArmor.htm#tableArmorSpecialAbilities) on page 217 of the DMG, which includes several prices for unique abilities.

When pricing, do you add the 50% price increase for "Creating Wondrous Items" as shown on DMG p.285?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wondrous Items are things that *aren't* Weapons or Armor.

To calculate the cost of magic weapons or armor, you just add the costs listed.

- First, add all the Enhancement Bonus-equivalent abilities to its *actual* enhancement bonus (must be +1 to +5) to get a total (max +10)
- Look up the cost of that bonus on the appropriate table, and add it to the base cost of the weapon/armor (*must be* Masterwork, *can be* made of [special materials](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialMaterials.htm))
- Add any fixed-price ability costs

This will give the base cost, which will be the cost to buy it.
(If your character is crafting it themselves, the base cost is halved.)

Comment: Thank you, I also found a specific source stating what you say. 
Page. 217 on the DMG 
_"Magic Armor and Shield Special Ability Descriptions"_
_"Most magic armor and shields only have enhancement bonuses. Such items can also have one or more of the special abilities detailed below"_

Comment: Also, look up the new rules for magic item creation in the MIC. It explicitly updated the DMG rules.

Comment: @Simon: Also note that to apply an ability with an enhancement bonus cost, you need the weapon or armor to have an enhancement bonus of at least +1. You cannot for example apply Heavy Fortification (+5) and Freedom (+5) to an armor or shield, as you first need them to be +1 before being able to apply other enhancements (and +1+5+5 > +10).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thank you, I was wondering about items that does not have a  enhancment cost meassured in +1, +2 etc but those with a set gold price but thanks anyways! :)